# Receive a jagged array in query parameters

Tags: api, asp.net-core, get, query-string

I currently have a controller with an action that fetches some information, this action receives as a query param a jagged array to filter the information, example: `[["Day", ">=", "01.01.2021"],["User", "=", "SomeUserId"]]`.

My current action declarion:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<object> Get(string[][] filters)
{
     ...
}
```

When I make an AJAX request from the client the URL goes encoded in the following way (DevTools request header parameters view):

```
filters[0][]: Day
filters[0][]: >=
filters[0][]: 01.07.2021
filters[1][]: User
filters[1][]: =
filters[1][]: SomeUserId
```

Url Encoded FYI: `...filters%5B0%5D%5B%5D=Day&filters%5B0%5D%5B%5D=%3E%3D&filters%5B0%5D%5B%5D=01.07.2021&filters%5B1%5D%5B%5D=User&filters%5B1%5D%5B%5D=%3D&filters%5B1%5D%5B%5D=SomeUserId`

**The problem**

My action when receives the information above has the value of two empty string arrays `string[2][]`. The following image is a debug print screen from VS of the filters variable.
[image]

Should I serialize? Or use a different structure?

Comment: You can send the filter parameters as JSON and even bind them to a proper data structure: https://abdus.dev/posts/aspnetcore-model-binding-json-query-params/

Comment: Hi @Filipe Nóbrega, I think you need send request url like: `https://localhost:portNumber/weatherforecast?filters[0][0]=Day&filters[0][1]=%3E=&filters[0][2]=01.07.2021&filters[1][0]=User&filters[1][1]==&filters[1][2]=2` and add `[FromQuery]` before parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

View:

```
<button type="button" onclick="SendRequest()">Click</button>
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    function SendRequest() {
        var day = "Day";
        var simble = encodeURIComponent(">=");
        var date = "01.07.2021";
        var user = "UserName";
        var simble2 = "=";
        var id = "1";
        $.ajax({
            //url: "api/values?filters[0][0]=Day&filters[0][1]=>=&filters[0][2]=01.07.2021&filters[1][0]=User&filters[1][1]==&filters[1][2]=2"
            url: "api/values?filters[0][0]=" + day + "&filters[0][1]=" + simble + "&filters[0][2]=" + date + " &filters[1][0]=" + user + "&filters[1][1]=" + simble2 + "&filters[1][2]=" + id + "",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (res) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        })
    }
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    public void Get([FromQuery] string[][] filters)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to wrap the input in a class like

```
public class InputRequest
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then use a custom model binder -

```
class InputRequestModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    static readonly JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(List<InputRequest>)) return Task.CompletedTask;

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None) return Task.CompletedTask;

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

        var results = valueProviderResult.Select(t => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<InputRequest>(t, options)).ToList();

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(results);

        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }
}
```

Lastly, hook the model binder to controller method -

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("show")]
public string Show([ModelBinder(typeof(InputRequestModelBinder))] List<InputRequest> req)
{
    //do something
}
```

Example usage -

```
/SomeController/show?req=%7B%0A%20%20%22field%22%3A%20%22name%22%2C%0A%20%20%22operator%22%3A%20%22%3D%22%2C%0A%20%20%22value%22%3A%20%22tom%22%0A%7D&req=%7B%0A%20%20%22field%22%3A%20%22age%22%2C%0A%20%20%22operator%22%3A%20%22%3C%22%2C%0A%20%20%22value%22%3A%20%2220%22%0A%7D
```

Decoded url looks like this -

```
/SomeController/show?req={
  "field": "name",
  "operator": "=",
  "value": "tom"
}&req={
  "field": "age",
  "operator": "<",
  "value": "20"
}
```

**Pro** -

- You get to explicitly state the contract to your API consumers about expected values in `InputRequest`

**Con** -

- Your request query string length increases, so you may hit the limit soon. Although you may convert it to a POST method, but then it violates REST principles.

Comment: _"Your request query string length increases"_ It actually decreases, JSON is terser than having to repeat the key prefix over and over.

Comment: Well, in JSON, you've got to repeat the fieldnames for every object. You could have represented single value with delimiter separated (comma say), which would be more concise, but not look as cleaner from a contract perspective.  eg. "req=name,eq,tom|age,lt,10"